# Dennis trace map for stable $\infty$-category, naively

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, infinity-categories

I'm trying to get more intiution about higher K-theory, Hochschild homology and the trace map between by thinking about these objects from an informal $\infty$-categorical perspective, instead of using very precise and concrete definitions:

Let $A$ be a small stable $\infty$-category. If my understanding is correct, the topological Hochschild homology of $A$ can be described as the co-end of spectra (where the Hom is the spectra enriched Hom of $A$):

$$ THH(A) :=  \int^A \text{Hom}(a,a) $$

Informally, it means that a map of spectrum $THH(A) \rightarrow X$ defines an $X$-valued trace for arrows in $A$, i.e. maps of spectrum $\text{Tr}_a : \text{Hom}(a,a) \to X $ which satisfies some coherence relation, the first one corresponding to "$\text{Tr}_b(fg)=\text{Tr}_a(gf)$" for $f:a \to b$ and $g: b \to a$, and higher one being coherence conditions for the trace of cyclic permutation of composite of an $n$-cycle of arrows in $A$. So $THH(A)$ is the target of the universal trace map for $A$.

On the other hand, the (connective) $K$-theory of $A$ can be seen as (for e.g. from Waldhausen construction) the target of the universal "Euler Characteristic" map for $A$, in the sense that a map of spectrum $K(A) \to X$ corresponds to an Euler characteristic $\chi(a) \in X$ for each $a \in A$,such that if $a \to b \to c$ is a fiber sequence then we have an equivalence $\chi(b) \simeq \chi(a)+\chi(c)$ also subject to some higher coherence conditions.

It hence sounds natural, that the Dennis trace map $K(A) \to THH(A)$ should, in this perspective, corresponds to the map informally defined as:

$$ \begin{array}{ccc} K(A) &\to & THH(A) \\
\chi(a) & \mapsto & \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a)
 \end{array}$$

To show that this defines maps, one needs to show that if $a \to b \to c$ is a fiber sequence in $A$ then, for any trace function as above, we can construct an equivalence $\text{Tr}(\text{Id}_b) \simeq \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a) + \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_c)$

Of course for a full proof that this map is well defined as a map of spectra (or rather $E_\infty$-algebras by identyfing connective spectra with grouplike $E_\infty$-algebra) we would also need to deal with the "higher coherence conditions", and show that this induce a map of groulike $E_\infty$ algebra, by dealing with more higher coherence condition and so one. But I'm focusing on the first condition as this is the first one I do not understand.

**Question:** *Can we give a formal/elementary proof that a trace map as above automatically comes with equivalences $\text{Tr}(\text{Id}_b) \simeq \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a) + \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_c)$ for each fiber sequence $a \to b \to c$.*

I think I know how to prove this using deeper theorem, for example the additivity of $THH$, but I'm really interested in a direct elementary proof of this.

To give an idea of the type of argument I accept as an answer, it is easy to give a formal proof that if $b = a \oplus c$ then $\text{Tr}(\text{Id}_b) = \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a) + \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_c)$. Indeed, as $a$ and $c$ are retract of $b=a \oplus c$, with idempotent $P_a,P_c:b \to b$. The property of the trace shows that:

$$ \text{Tr}(P_a) = \text{Tr}(i_a p_a) = \text{Tr}(p_a i_a) = \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a) $$

and $\text{Id}_b = P_a + P_c$ so:
 $$\text{Tr}(Id_b)= \text{Tr}(P_a)+ \text{Tr}(P_c) = \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_a) + \text{Tr}(\text{Id}_c)$$

Comment: As much as I'd love to take credit, it's the *Dennis* trace map :)

Comment: This paper of Groth, Ponto and Shulman seems to be an answer, doesn’t it? https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3277

Comment: This may be complemented by this paper of Galauer https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0153

Comment: But, historically, the first conceptual approach to this is this paper by Peter May https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf

Comment: @Denis-Charles : Thank you very much, that's very interesting! I haven't finish reading them yet (I definitely will) but from what I gathered so far, I'm not sure they answer the question however: they all prove additivity when the trace is defined as $Tr(f) = ev \circ (f \otimes Id) \circ coev$ for $f$ an endomorphism of a dualizable object. It does not seems to prove the results for a general "trace function" in the sense of a map out of THH(A) for a stable but not necessarily monoidal category A. But I'll keep reading, maybe the proof can be adapted...

Comment: Aren't all traces define like this? Also, I am not sure I understand your question, since the Dennis trace maps goes to THH, as opposed as to going from it. Another way to see THH consists in saying that there is a symmetric monoidal bicategory of stable $\infty$-categories (with bimodules as 1-cells) and that the trace map defines a functor from stable $\infty$-categories to spectra (since spectra form endomorphisms of the unit). The even more general framework where to look might be the one of higher categories in which every cell not in the top dimension has adjoints.

Comment: @Denis-Charles: Well the "trace" I'm considering here is the 'universal one' which sends an arrow $f:a \rightarrow a \in A$ to its image in THH(A) (defined as the coend in the question). To construct Dennis trace map, you need to show that this trace is additive (and other higher coherence condition), which is equivalent to proving that all traces functions are additive. I do not know how to define this 'trace' with value in THH(A) in terms of strong duality, especially that here A is not assumed to be monoidal.

Comment: It is the category of stable $\infty$-categories which is monoidal here, not $A$...

Comment: Otherwise, the existence of Dennis trace map is more about the universal property of $K$-theory: since $THH$ is additive (it takes Verdier quotients to fiber sequences of spectra) the spectrum of maps $K\to THH$ is equivalent to $THH(finite spectra)$, the $\pi_0$ of which being $\mathbf Z$ with the canonical element $1$. And if you take $\pi_0(THH(A))$, the Dennis trace map really is the very usual trace of the identity.

Comment: I'm aware of the characterization of THH(A) as a trace in the monoidal category of presentable stable $\infty$-categories, but I do not quite know how to use this to connect my question to the papers you mentioned, which apply to stable monoidal categories. I'm also aware of the construction of the trace map using the universal property of K-theory, in fact as mentioned in the question I know how to directly deduce the additivity of the THH(A) valued trace from the additivity of THH(A) itself, but I'm looking for something more direct/elementary (only involving diagram chasing in $A$).

Comment: The argument about the universal property of $K$-theory is diagram chasing (if you look at the proof). In fact, if you restrict to $K_0$ (i.e. gorget about higher coherence), this becomes completely elementary. Otherwise, you may be interested by the notion of shadow introduced by Shulman and Ponto in their paper "Duality and traces for indexed monoidal categories". The case of $THH$ is discussed explicitly in this paper of Campbell and Ponto: arXiv:1803.01284.The later is the point of view of $THH$ as a trace.

Comment: I believe one can extract an argument of the type you're looking for from the proof of lemma 3.2.10 in Madsen's *Algebraic K-theory and traces*. I don't have time to do it right now, but I plan to go back to this and write an answer following these lines if I ever have the time to breathe again :). (essentially you're asking why $THH_0(S_2C)=THH_0(C)×THH_0(C)$)